# Is there a specific chance of hatching a shiny in X and Y using the Masuda Method?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

I've been breeding a Japanese Manectric and my Luxray in hopes of getting a shiny Shinx, but then I was wondering.
What is the rate of getting a shiny? I search around the web and saw a few, the most being 1/1000.
But I couldn't tell if it was confirmed. Does anyone know? :/

Comment: In past games it's been ~1/6000 but people believe it may have been increased in the current games. Though I have yet to see confirmed numbers.